# How to make a link go to its corresponding href, if the files are not in the same folder?

Tags: html

I don't know how Return to Menu (for if you are in info) doesn't find startmenu.html though I know that it should. After all, all of the other Return to Menu's work and I am using the same exact line of code for all of them.

info.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
        <style type="text/css">
          ol {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0
          }

          table td,table th {
              padding: 0
          }

          .c1 {
              color: #000000;
              font-weight: 700;
              text-decoration: none;
              vertical-align: baseline;
              font-size: 14pt;
              font-family: "Arial";
              font-style: normal
          }

          .c3 {
              color: #000000;
              font-weight: 400;
              text-decoration: none;
              vertical-align: baseline;
              font-size: 12pt;
              font-family: "Arial";
              font-style: normal
          }

          .c2 {
              padding-top: 0pt;
              padding-bottom: 0pt;
              line-height: 1.15;
              orphans: 2;
              widows: 2;
              text-align: left
          }

          .c5 {
              color: #000000;
              text-decoration: none;
              vertical-align: baseline;
              font-family: "Arial";
              font-style: normal
          }

          .c8 {
              color: #000000;
              text-decoration: none;
              vertical-align: baseline;
              font-family: "Arial";
              font-style: italic
          }

          .c7 {
              background-color: #ffffff;
              max-width: 468pt;
              padding: 72pt 72pt 72pt 72pt
          }

          .c0 {
              font-size: 12pt;
              font-weight: 700
          }

          .c4 {
              color: inherit;
              text-decoration: inherit
          }

          .c6 {
              height: 11pt
          }
          </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p class="c2">
            <span class="c3">Tittle: Patrol Turned Bad</span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2 c6">
            <span class="c3"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2">
            <span class="c3">By: Erik P. Kountzman</span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2 c6">
            <span class="c3"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2">
            <span class="c3">Rating: Rated A for Adult, Adult audience only, 18+ only</span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2 c6">
            <span class="c3"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2">
            <span class="c3">This game has: Nudity, Sex, Violince, Substunces, Sexual Assault (Rape), Graphic Depiction of Under Aged Sex, Graphic Depiction of Under Aged Sexual Assault (Rape), Gore, language, Graphic Depiction of Under Aged Nudity, Suicide, Sexual Harassment, Graphic Depiction of Under Aged Sexual Harassment, smoking</span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2 c6">
            <span class="c3"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2">
            <span class="c3">By the year 2021 season 1 chapter 1 storyline will be complete, status will reman as in development until the latest of the year 2030 and the erlist of 2026.</span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2 c6">
            <span class="c3"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2">
            <span class="c3">By the year 2026 this game will have voice actors, images, vidios, and sound in it. Uknown amount of seasons. All images and vidios will be drawing and/or animated type of images and vidios, their might be some images and videos of drawn under aged males and/or under aged females have sex with other under aged people and/or with adult and/or being raped by other under aged people and/or with adults.</span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2 c6">
            <span class="c3"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2">
            <span class="c3">Final Upload Location:</span>
            <span class="c3">
              <a href="https://itch.io/game/classification/731822">https://itch.io/game/classification/731822</a>
            </span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2 c6">
            <span class="c3"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2">
            <span class="c3">Upload Status: In Development</span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2 c6">
            <span class="c3"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2">
            <span class="c3">Description: Patrol Turned Bad (The Adventures of Miya Armeon) is a multi season interactive story where you play as Federal Special Operations Agent of the "FBI" it really isn't much of the FBI since this takes place in the UnderWorld. The Special Operations Agent (NSOA) is named Miya Armeon, Miya Armeon works for an agency called the Netherrack Agency (NA). Miya Armeon is one of the characters of Hell's Story. (Link to Hell's Story:
              <a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Sr9nZmLgYVEaRevnDAFy3b8n_w044v5X?usp=sharing">https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Sr9nZmLgYVEaRevnDAFy3b8n_w044v5X?usp=sharing</a>)
            Miya Armeon's gender is female, but I give you an option between wether she is male or female in Patrol Turned Bad. After all she technically doesn't have a gender since she can change her body into what ever living creature she wants with restrictions. She can have the form of a male or the form of a female or a mixed form of a male and female, basicually she can have only a dick and a buthole and/or only a pussy, tits, and a buthole and/or only a dick, a pussy, tits, and a buthole. Her classification of a demon would be a Demon Cat, her type of Demon Cat is known as a Hell Cat, but she is not any ordanary Hell Cat, she is the Hellfire Cat. There is more info about Miya Armeon if you go to the link for Hell's Story, after clicking it go to The Library of Knowledge (Data, Info of Understanding), then go to Hellfire Nation, then go to Hellfire Generals, then go to Hellfire Cat, then go to Miya Armeon, and finally click the file that is named Miya Armeon Personality 1. After all that file is her true personality, her first personality.</span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2 c6">
            <span class="c3"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2">
            <span class="c3">Description of Season 1: Season 1 of Patrol Turned Bad (Chapter 1) is about the NA trying to find a wanted criminal that has the name of Jerren Dannoto, but something bad happens. Jerren Dannoto kiddnaps you and he forces you to do some weird things with a girl named Lily. (Chapter 2) Forcing you to try and break out of the warehouse with Lily when Jerren is not looking. (Chapter 3) However when you and Lily were about to get out of the warehouse Jerren catches you and Lily. (Chapter4) Then he throughs you and Lily into a room that has no windows, one bed, a toilet, a sink, a shower, and lights with no privicy. (Chapter 5) But you and Lily are not the only ones in that room, there is a girl named Laura in the room with you and she looks all sad and depressed. (Chapter 6) So, you, Lily, and Laura are trying to excape the room and (Chapter 7) then find a way to excape the warehouse and (Chapter 8) make it all the way to safty at a NA building and (Chapter 9) then try to catch Jerren Dannoto. (Chapter 10) After catching Jerren Dannoto you have to transport him to the transport sight. (Chapter 11) Then you have to make sure that Jerren gets to the drop off zone. (Chapter 12) Then you can go and support Jerren's newest victims, Lily and Laura, and just be there for them as they recover from the traumatic experience. (Season Ends) You, Lily, and Laura get to have the "good fun" with each other??? Will you be able to excape Jerren Dannoto alive? Are you capable of catching Jerren Dannoto alive or dead? If you think you are up for the task then play and see where the Adventures of Miya Armeon will get you.</span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2 c6">
            <span class="c3"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2">
            <span class="c3">
              <a class="c9" href="startmenu.html">Return to main menu</a>
            </span>
      </p>
      <p class="c2 c6">
            <span class="c3"></span>
      </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some more clarity go to this link: https://repl.it/@Erik1Kountzman/Patrol-Turned-Bad and then after press go, go down to info and go down to the bottom and click Return to Menu and you will know what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of the problem is evident in your off-site example, but not in the code you're showing.  So it seems you're looking in the wrong place.

Your other pages can use this link because they're all in the same folder as the "menu" page:

```
<a class="c9" href="startmenu.html">Return to main menu</a>
```

But what makes the "info" page different?  It's in a different folder.  So to get back to the "menu" page you need to navigate back up one folder:

```
<a class="c9" href="../startmenu.html">Return to main menu</a>
```

Or directly to the root folder:

```
<a class="c9" href="/startmenu.html">Return to main menu</a>
```

---

Note: The term "folder" here is kind of a misnomer, but the analogy applies.  We're actually talking about URLs, nothing to do with a file system.  But the `/` character is still used to hierarchically separate them much like a file system in this way.  And for simple websites like this one, the URLs and the files/folders directly map to one another so the relative paths are still the same.